# the_permalink() not working

Tags: permalinks, installation, configuration

I have WordPress installed in a subfolder called `news`, but links to comments, posts, categories, etc all link to `domain.com/?p=99` instead of `domain.com/news/?p=99`. The only link that points to the correct folder is the `edit post` link.

I have set my WP folder to, `domain.com/news`, and my site domain, `domain.com`. I also tried deleting my `.htaccess` file. Nothing has helped!

Part of the issue might step from the fact that WP *used* to be installed in the root folder.

Any idea what I can do? :(

Comment: Have you flushed the permalink cache (simply by visiting _Settings > Permalinks_) after moving the website in the `news` subfolder?

Comment: Did you read the [**Giving WordPress Its Own Directory**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) Codex entry?

Comment: @ChipBennett, Hmm. I've followed those instructions except for the part which says to copy the `index.php` to the root folder. I don't want the www.domain.com/ to be the WordPress blog. Only www.domain.com/news/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is because the "Site URL" field in Settings > General is wrong. It probably says "domain.com" where it should say "domain.com/news".

Comment: You sir, are a genius! Thanks so much! I thought the Site URL was for other content, but no, it's for the blog itself, just like the separate WordPress URL. Thanks again!